# Составление регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется такой вот текстовый файл:

```
some text {
 type1 someparam1;
 type2 someparam2;
 subtype::type3 someparam3;
 subtype4 type4 someparam4;
}
```

На выходе хочу получить

```
someparam1 = type1;
someparam2 = type2;
someparam3 = subtype3::type3;
someparam4 = subtype4 type4;
```

Естесно все это хочу получить регуляркой. Проблема в том, что хочу как можно меньше кода, соответственно сделать все надо 1 регуляркой.

Если это реально, то прошу поделиться мыслями если же нет, то переходим к плану Б:

Вот две регулярки которые я составил/нашел

```
#\{((?>[^{}]+)|(?R))*\}# - получаем все что в кв скобках
/(.*)[;]/ - расфасовывам все что внутри.
```

Как видно из примера мне осталась одна регулярка которая будет разделять все по **последнему** пробелу.

Comment: Фигурные скобки могут быть вложены друг в друга?

Comment: Нет, в моем примере все возможные комбинации

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать такие выражения только из теоретического любопытства. Лучше сделайте два выражения.

```
$text=<<<HEREDOC
some text {
    type1 someparam1;
    type2 someparam2;
    subtype::type3 someparam3;
    subtype4 type4 someparam4;
}
HEREDOC;
echo preg_replace("/.*?\\{|(?<=\\n)[ \\t]+|\\n}.*$|(?:(.*?) +([^ ]+)(;)(?=(?s:.*( = ))))/", "$2$4$1$3", $text." = ");
```

Результат:

```
someparam1 = type1;
someparam2 = type2;
someparam3 = subtype::type3;
someparam4 = subtype4 type4;
```

---

**UPD:**
Хотя используйте и в реальном коде. Произвел замер скорости: это выражение всего лишь в полтора раза дольше выполняется, чем два более эффективных выражения. При малом количестве повторений потеря производительности не существенна, зато на две строки в коде меньше.